# CSS drop-shadow inset for IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

i've been reading and experimenting with conditional css to display the following css for IE 8.

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px  inset, 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0 16px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset, 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
```

I have been fiddling with gradient and offset but i can not find anything about inset without having to create additional elements.

is is possible to 3 insets and use rgba, as using the gradient start and end for ie was a standard gradient. If not i will happily use basic styling and drop the css3 styling, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it is not supported; http://dimox.net/cross-browser-css3-box-shadow/... However, take in consideration your analytics data and see how many visitors are really using ie8, maybe it's only a small percentage, and it's not that much of a mis;)

Comment: Thanks, am abit of an obsessive when it comes to cross browser, just to ensure the site looks as I intended on every browser/ device. Well as close as possible.